# How to listen for a checkbox in a listview row?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listener

```
String[] from = new String[] { CallrzDbAdapter.C_NAME,CallrzDbAdapter.C_EMAIL,CallrzDbAdapter.C_PHONE };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.cName, R.id.cEmail, R.id.cPhone };


    notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

    ListView view =getListView();
    view.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    view.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello"+position+" is clicked ",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
      });

    //setListAdapter(notes);
    setListAdapter(notes);
```

I have a custom layout for the list row which has a checkbox as well. How can I create a listener for the checkbox event? I have searched and heard about bindView but is there anyone can explain it a bit more clearly?  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702877/update-a-checkbox-in-listview-row-that-corresponds-to-a-database-row) is the link someone explained it but I couldnt plug it in my code.

Comment: Why not add a OnClickListener() to the checkbox?

Comment: how? First I need to get a reference for the checkox some how somewhere to add a listener to it. And also how am I gonna make sure which row the checkbox belongs to? this is like a listview and every row in the list has a checkbox. Could you give an example of it pls?

Comment: you can get the CheckBox with findViewById(), then you can set its tag equal to its position in the listview, then when the checkbox is clicked you can examine the tag to see which checkbox was clicked.

Comment: sounds great :) but can u give an example of it pls. If I was that good I would figure it out by myself I think.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create your own ViewBinder and in setViewValue simply do something like:

```
 class MyViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
   int id = view.getId();
   /* handle this particular item from our own view
   if (id == R.id.myViewId) {
    ((CheckBox) view).setOnItemLongClickListener(...);
    ((CheckBox) view).setText(...);
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
 }
```

You can thenjust use SampleAdapter for data and call

`adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());`

Comment: Tahnk you firstly this seems to be right direction but I need more help. If you look at the code above where should I place this?

Comment: The idea of a ViewBinder is to allow customizing a row in a list. You are getting Object that was associated with a View for this row (i.e. what you are doing with mapping of fields to views). If you return false, the default setting will occur. But when you return true, this means your ViewBinder did the binding for this particular View and Object.

This way you check that id of the view matches - for example if you have <CheckBox android:id="@id/+myViewId" ...>, you can check if id == R.id.myViewId and then perform certain actions.

You can set bindings to this view inside the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `view` from `onItemLongClick` should contain your checkbox.

You can retreive it like you normally would:

```
Checkbox yourCheckbox = (Checkbox) view.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, I normally use a Custom `ArrayAdapter`

EDIT:

You could look at this for an example.
[Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)
Hint: it's the `getView` in the example where you can `findViewById` your `CheckBox`

Comment: the thing is I dont want the checkbox towork when the row is long clicked. without writing any code , the checkbox is already can be checked and unchecked. the question is how can I listen it and run an event. If I place as u said the checkbox in onItemLongClick that wouldnt be I think right. I want it to work when I check and uncheck it. must be a place that would work all the time

Comment: Try the tutorial I posted under EDIT. You can create a Custom ListView with a Custom ArrayAdapter and set listeners on the checkboxes before it is loaded. I've done this before myself.