# ListView- EditText as a row - SimpleCursorAdapter - Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a ListView that uses a EditText as a row. I populate the ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter from SQLLite DB. As I look at UI, I see a bunch of EditText prepopulated with default data in the screen. I want the user to change that default text and eventually persist in database. I am not able to get a handle to user changed text for the EditText boxes in the ListView..Did anyone experienced the same scenario or suggest someother approach..appreciate your help!

btw I am using Android 2.3.3

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a ViewBinder to your adapter, with `setViewBinder(...)` method, and set listeners for your editTexts in `setViewValue(...)` method. or you can write your own custom adapter class instead of using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: can you please provide some sample code..Appreciate it! I have been trying with no luck so far.

Comment: btw i am trying this...
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int ci) {
              if(ci==3){
              final EditText v1 = (EditText) view;  
              v1.setText(cursor.getString(ci));
              v1.setFocusable(true);
              v1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                     
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}   }

Comment: this can help: http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/29/simpleadapter-viewbinders/ look at the "ToolBinder" class and see what's going on there. you can set an instance of your class (which extends ViewBinder just like ToolBinder in the given link) to your adapter by calling adapter.setViewBinder(instace_of_view_binder) and then in your ViewBinder class, when setting values for views of that adapter, set a listener on the editTexts. 
this example also will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639779/how-to-listen-for-a-checkbox-in-a-listview-row

Comment: In one sentence, setting viewBinder to an adapter is controlling how the adapter sets the given values to the views of each item of the adapter, but there you have access to views and you can set listeners on them.

Comment: I did follow all those..but what i am learning is adding listeners to EditText (especially for all the rows in ListView is a bad idea). It keeps updating DB(in my case) whenever i do something and requerying the cursor.. Dont you think so?

Comment: could you please describe the last sentence? (It keeps updating DB ... ) Did you mean it's not efficient to query DB every time the text of EditText changes, or something else?